# How do I associate command objects with the right receiver?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I tried to use [Command Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern) for implementing Undo and Redo in my project

```
public abstract class Command
{
    protected Form Receiver { set; get; }
    protected HtmlElement Element { set; get; }
    abstract public void ReDo();
    abstract public void UnDo();
    public Command(Form receiver)
    {
        this.Receiver = receiver;
    }
}
class AddElementCmd : Command
{        
    public AddElementCmd(HtmlElement elem, Form receiver)
        : base(receiver)
    {
        Element = elem;
    }
    public override void ReDo()
    {
        ((FormEdit)Receiver).AddElement(Element,false);
    }
    public override void UnDo()
    {
        ((FormEdit)Receiver).DelElement(Element, false);
    }
}
class DelElementCmd : Command
{
    public DelElementCmd(HtmlElement elem, Form receiver)
        : base(receiver)
    {
        Element = elem;
    }
    public override void ReDo()
    {
        ((FormEdit)Receiver).DelElement(Element, false);
    }
    public override void UnDo()
    {
        ((FormEdit)Receiver).AddElement(Element, false);
    }
}
```

Implementation of `AddElement` command in `FormEdit`.

```
public void AddElement(HtmlElement elem, bool isNew = true)
{
    IHTMLElement2 dom = elem.DomElement as IHTMLElement2;
    if (isNew)
    {
        Command cmd = new AddElementCmd(elem, this);
        Undo.Push(cmd);
        Redo.Clear();
    }    
    // some codes here....
    if (showAlltoolStripButton.Checked)
    {
        dom.runtimeStyle.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else if (showSelectionToolStripButton.Checked)
    {
        dom.runtimeStyle.visibility = "visible";
    }
 }
...
```

the `Undo` and `Redo` stacks are stored in the `FormMain` class and are passed to the editor form.

```
public Stack<Command> Undo = new Stack<Command>();
public Stack<Command> Redo = new Stack<Command>();

....
FormEdit editor = new FormEdit ();
editor.Browser = webBrowser1;
editor.addedElements = addedElements;
editor.restoreElements = restoreElements;
editor.Undo = Undo;
editor.Redo = Redo;
```

When in a new `FormEdit` the user clicks on Redo or Undo button, the corresponding function in the `FormEdit` is executed, but as I checked this receiver of the command is the form in which the command was first created and now may has been disposed. I expect that the program raise an error, but it seems the `Command` object stores a reference to the old form and this leads to misbehavior.

Therefore, I think that I must find a consistent receiver for the commands, either the main form or the webBrowser control, which has the same life time as the commands themselves. But yet I should have access to some controls related to the commands.

Where is the best place to implement the command functions as the receiver of `Command` objects? Or any other way to associate the new form to a command popped from stack.

Comment: I think this decision is on you. We can't help you because we don't know the specification or functional requirements of your application.

Comment: I believe Command objects should only contain serializable data (i.e., no references to other objects) since common uses for them include sending their serialized forms across networks, saving them to a file for later, or replaying them on a different receiver (if you want your changes to show up on my screen in real time, for instance). That may mean you want to pass in the Receiver to each command method, or maybe give the Receiver executeCommand()/undoCommand() methods that let it pass itself in, or maybe use command objects that only contain method names/arguments instead of code.

Comment: [An implementation example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33384/Multilevel-Undo-and-Redo-Implementation-in-Cshar). And, [an SO discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541383/undo-redo-implementation)

Comment: @Ixrec Thank you for your advice, then you mean  I should be able to set the `Receiver` of each command object, I am going to do this.

Comment: Consider using the memento pattern instead.

Comment: Does your program deal with any sort of Model? I notice code dealing with `Element`'s and the DOM...  You you have some central `Document` or similar?  Because that is what each `Command` should have as a `Receiver` IMHO.

Comment: Just a side note, sometimes it's easier to implement undo/redo by only saving a protocol of changes/commands without explicit undo. You can do an undo by replaying the protocol until one step before the current one. A full state save every x steps makes this scalable.

Comment: Might be easier to remove the Receiver reference in the Command and simply store the Commands with the relevant form, that way they are destroyed with the form.  Depends on your exact architecture

Answer (score 1):

The *Command* pattern should apply to the *model*, and not the UI. In your case, make it

```
protected HtmlDocument Receiver { set; get; }
protected HtmlElement Element { set; get; }
```

To update the UI, use the *Observer* pattern, so all open forms and their controls can react to changes in the underlying model.

Your code will become clearer and more decoupled because *Command* can take care of only changing the document, and the *observers* in the UI only have to update the controls without regard to exactly what changed.

When a form closes, it will unregister itself as an observer, and no references to it will be kept.

If a new form is opened after a change to the document, it will be notified after an *undo* even if it wasn't present when the original change was made.